# css styling of points in figure

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I created an `nvd3` type graph with the `rCharts` package. I saved it in a standalone `html` and am importing it into an `rmarkdown` document with `<iframe src = 'Figure.html'>`.

[image]

I looked at the `html` source in Chrome and Firefox via the 'inspect element' feature and found that the following edits to the `css`:

```
.nvd3.nv-line .nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point {
    stroke-width: 10px;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
}
```

gives:

[image]

which is the effect I want to obtain. However, if I insert the above code into the `css`, it is not 'picked up'. Other stylings are picked up, so the css is being read, but the above seems to be discarded. Any ideas?

The `html` figure is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b187e77d795e5bf96f51

**EDIT** Cracked this one thanks to jbaums and a hint by sal niro. Here's the workflow to transform an `rCharts` `nPlot` with 'lineChart' into a combination of 'lineChart' and 'scatterChart'. This is the relevant part of your `rmarkdown` code:

````
 ```{r 'Figure'}  
require(rCharts)
load("data/df.Rda") 
# round data for rChart tooltip display
df$value <- round(df$value, 2)
n <- nPlot(value ~ Year, group = 'variable', data = df, type = 'lineChart') 
n$yAxis(axisLabel = 'Labor and capital income (% national income)')
n$chart(margin = list(left = 100)) # margin makes room for label
n$yAxis(tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return Math.round(d*100*100)/100 + '%'} !#")
n$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Year')
n$chart(useInteractiveGuideline=TRUE)
n$chart(color = colorPalette)
n$addParams(height = 500, width = 800)
n$setTemplate(afterScript = '<style>
  .nv-point {
    stroke-opacity: 1!important;
    stroke-width: 6px!important;
    fill-opacity: 1!important;
  } 
</style>'
)
n$save('figures/Figure.html', standalone = TRUE)
```
````

Comment: you likely need to do this through the JS through an `append().attr()` function

Comment: @salniro, Oh I have no idea what that involves! any hint appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I had the same gotcha with D3. Needs to be done when adding the `svg` element in the JS hope you find it!

Comment: Thanks, I can see the svg element when I inspect the code, so I'll see if that gets me anywhere. Also, I'm reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript, but I'm none the wiser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you specify the rules as [`!important`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9245353/489704), then they won't be overruled later (though support for `!important` is limited in some old versions of IE).

Add the following between the `<style>` and `</style>` tags of your html file:

```
.nv-point {
  stroke-opacity: 1 !important;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  fill-opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Rendered in Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m:
[image]

And in Firefox 34.0.5 and IE 11:
[image]

Comment: haha I always thought that was just a user comment when I saw it

Comment: @jbaums, thanks! Indeed, that works (took me a little while to test I could only make it to work within the html inside between ``<style>`` and could not make it to work inside the ``css`` for some reason (though that may be something I overlooked). Now I'm trying to work out how to produce the html figure with that style embedded to begin with, but I guess it's a separate question!

Answer (score 1):

**How to highlight a single point**

I was working on a solution on how to highlight single points within the line and wanted to share it, since I did not found something similar yet:

```
var highlightSinglePoint = function(point){
    var selector = 'nv-point-'+point;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    x["0"].style["fillOpacity"] = "1";
    x["0"].style["strokeWidth"] = "5px";
    x["0"].style["strokeOpacity"] = "1";
}
```

You might also want to reset these css styles on your lastly highlighted point before highlighting another one. 
Note: Selecting 'nv-point-XYZ' will select point XYZ of all your d3 linecharts. So if you have multiple charts in your application, then dont forget to adapt the selecter with a HTML id of your chart or whatsoever.